# array difference works not correct

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 array which I compare to get the difference:

```
Array 1 
(
    [salutation] => 
    [fname] => Max
    [lname] => Mustermann
)

Array 2
(
    [salutation] => Herr
    [fname] => Max2
    [lname] => Mustermann2
)
```

I compare them like this:

```
$keys = array_keys(array_diff($array1,$array2));
```

And the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => fname
    [1] => lname
)
```

Which is correctly but I miss "salutation". It is different, too.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your code works for me, what am I missing to reproduce? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cbfc26268c0e2a35d066668b79ccf33143dda8eb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of `array_diff` is:

```php
array_diff(array $array, array ...$arrays): array
```

> Compares array against one or more other arrays and returns the values in array that are not present in any of the other arrays.

Comparison is done by value. `salutation` doesn't actually have a value in the source array, so it is not included in the result.

Consider using `array_diff_assoc`.

Answer (score 0):

If you watch on the PHP documentation here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

You can see that it checks every item in the array (first argument in array_diff) that has a value. Since salutation in array1 is null it doesn't get compared. Hope this helps you out!

Greetings :)